# Why is my SVG coordinate system supporting negative coordinates?

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I am trying to draw a rectangle in React-Native using the `react-native-svg` package as follows:

```js
<View
  style={{
    width: '100%',
    height: 200,
    borderWidth: 1,
  }}
>
  <Svg height='200' width='100%' viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
    <Rect
      x='-10'
      y='10'
      rx='10'
      ry='10'
      width='70'
      height='10'
      fill='#ddd'
      stroke='black'
      strokeWidth='2'
    />
  </Svg>
</View>
```

I was thinking that the top-left corner of the coordinate system would be (0,0), so the rectangle should be cut off. However, I end up seeing the whole rectangle.

[image]

Can anyone explain why this is happening? I was thinking that the viewport and the viewbox would have the same coordinate system so there wouldn't be any transformations going on.

Comment: it's because you have `width='100%'`.  Depending on the width of the container the svg element may be stretched. If you don't want to see the negative part of the svg canvas preserve the aspect ratio i.e either delete the height of the svg element or use a width of 200

Comment: [MDN link for preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio). For `meet` (the default for meet/slice): "if the aspect ratio of the graphic does not match the viewport, some of the viewport will extend beyond the bounds of the viewBox". With `xMidYMid` (the default alignment), the extra width will be distributed to the left and right, so you may see parts with negative x.
For `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"`, then parts with negative x will be cut off, but parts to the right beyond the viewBox may become visible.